# Changing the conditions of an if statement inside a function for C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am in the process of cleaning up some code, more with the incentive to improve. I have a button that switches on and off some text.  It works by using a pointer, clicking on a button and fading out all items, except the one clicked:

```
  public void OnHideClick()
{
    AllText.Remove(this.gameObject);
    if (newSwitchOne)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            switchOn = true;
        }
    }
    else if (newSwitchTwo)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            switchOff = true;
        }
    }
}
```

An update runs the actions depending on what boolean is true and ignores the false version. This works fine.

```
  void Update()
{
    if (switchOn)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            TextMesh TextColor = AllText[j].GetComponent<TextMesh>();
            TextColor.color = Color.Lerp(TextColor.color, new Color(255, 255, 255, 0), 0.0075f * Time.time);
            if (TextColor.color.a <= 0.023f)
            {
                TextColor.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);
                if (TextColor.color.a == 0.0f)
                {
                    switchOn = false;
                    switchOff = false;
                    newSwitchOne = false;
                    newSwitchTwo = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    if (switchOff)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            TextMesh TextColor = AllText[j].GetComponent<TextMesh>();
            TextColor.color = Color.Lerp(TextColor.color, new Color(255, 255, 255, 1), 0.005f * Time.time);
            if (TextColor.color.a >= 0.977f)
            {
                TextColor.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 1);
                if (TextColor.color.a == 1.0f)
                {
                    switchOn = false;
                    switchOff = false;
                    newSwitchOne = true;
                    newSwitchTwo = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to clean up this code.  I know of functions and CoRoutines well enough and by seeing similar code for if switchOn and if switchOff I am wondering can I clean this up by passing a few values in as arguments.  I have tried this and seem to have difficulty with the condition of the if statements that test the value of the color.alpha, for example:

```
if (TextColor.color.a >= 0.977f)
```

I know of sys.action but this doesn't seem to play ball.  As far as I see tell I believe changing the less than or more than symbol '<', '>' as an argument would 
help.  I've done some searching - but not finding much to help me out.  Maybe looking in the wrong direction.

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Action won't do as they don't return any value. But Func will.

```
void MyMethodWithCondition(Func<bool>condition)
{
    if(condition == null){ return; } // or throw exception
    if(condition() == true)
    {
          // Do something
    }
}
```

And here is how you use it:

```
MyMethodWithCondition(()=>{ return  TextColor.color.a >= 0.977f; });
MyMethodWithCondition(()=>{ return  TextColor.color.a <= 0.977f; });
```

Func can also take one or many arguments : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you Everts - this was exactly what I was after and with some tinkering it helped me learn some more.  I am grateful for all the helpful comments - I am sure each will help me in some way or another with future development on further understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work? *I have attempted to identify the commonality of the code to try and reduce some of the duplication.*

```
void Update()
{
    var color = switchOn ? new Color(255, 255, 255, 0) : new Color(255, 255, 255, 1);
    var multiplier = switchOn ? 0.0075f : 0.005f;

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        TextMesh TextColor = AllText[j].GetComponent<TextMesh>();
        TextColor.color = Color.Lerp(TextColor.color, color, multiplier * Time.time);
        if ((switchOn && TextColor.color.a <= 0.023f) || (!switchOn && TextColor.color.a >= 0.977f))
        {
            TextColor.color = color;
            if ()
            {
                switchOn = false;
                switchOff = false;
                newSwitchOne = !switchOn;
                newSwitchTwo = switchOn;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Or just do `if(switchOn ? TextColor.color.a <= 0.023f : (TextColor.color.a >= 0.977f))`

Comment: Good idea @JakubDąbek !

Answer (score 2):

```
public void OnHideClick()
{
  AllText.Remove(this.gameObject);
  if (newSwitchOne)
  {
      switchOn = true;
  }
  else if (newSwitchTwo)
  {
      switchOff = true;
  }
}
```

then

```
void Update()
{
    if (switchOn || switchOff)
    {
        var alpha = switchOn ? 0 : 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            TextMesh TextColor = AllText[j].GetComponent<TextMesh>();
            TextColor.color = Color.Lerp(TextColor.color, new Color(255, 255, 255, alpha), 0.0075f * Time.time);
            if ((TextColor.color.a <= 0.023f && switchOn) || (TextColor.color.a >= 0.977f && switchOff))
            {
                TextColor.color = new Color(255, 255, 255, alpha);
                switchOn = false;
                switchOff = false;
                newSwitchOne = switchOff;
                newSwitchTwo = switchOn;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What other answers missed is that at some moment both switchOn and switchOff flags become false and we shouldn't do anything on Update in that case.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create code depending of a condition/value, using this notation can lead to clean and flexible code :

```
test ? value1 : value2
```

If you're not used to this notation, here how it works : test condition, if true use value1, else use value2.

For example :

```
float testVal = 
if (TextColor.color.a == (switchOn ? 0.0f : 1.0f))
...
```

In above example, I assume you can use switchOn alone (switchOn true > your switchOn, switchOn false > your switchOff)